# How can I run flash automatically Chromium 62.0.3202.62?

Tags: flash, chromium, autorun, policy

I´m running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with Chromium 62.0.3202.62.
I need a way to run flash automatically for a small project which runs local content. In the settings you only have two options for flash to run. Ask first or block flash. I have tried adding file:///* to allowed sites but still need to click to allow the flash to run on startup. 
I have also added my own policy to /etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/ with the DefaultPluginsSetting parameter like so :

```
{ "DefaultPluginsSetting":1 }
```

And tried that with and without quotations.

Links for reference:

[How to set the policy file](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)

[DefaultPluginsSetting](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultPluginsSetting)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The policy setting and whitelisting was the key. My problem was that a script starting the browser was starting it on ingocnito, so it discarded any predefined site settings.